# C# & ASP.NET - Anyone create a library to talk to EdgeCast CDN via FTP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, cdn

For one of my projects we utilize a Content Delivery Network ([EdgeCast](http://www.edgecast.com/verticals/cdn.htm?gclid=CN3UptGU0ZwCFQhV2godxXdgJw)) and I was wondering if anyone knew of an existing (open source) library for C# that we could leverage?  In a nutshell, I am investigating the ability to create directories, upload files, and allow some general maintenance (rename files, delete files) via our admin panel.  Any insight would be appreciated.

---

**NOTE**:  My code to do this.  I don't know if they have an updated API at this point so please check.  This code is circa 2009 (as-is, no warranties, use at your own risk, etc).

**EdgeCast.cs**

```
using System;
using edgeCastWS = [DOMAIN].com.edgecast.api.EdgeCastWebServices;

namespace [DOMAIN].IO.ContentDeliveryNetwork
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <b>Authentication</b>
    /// <para>Each web service call will include a string parameter called strCredential which will ensure that customers may only access data related to their own accounts. This credential is a string made up of a few separate pieces of information.</para>
    /// <para>A typical credential a customer would use may look like: “c:bas:user@email.com:password”</para>
    /// <para> * The field format of this string is delimited with a colon “:” character.</para>
    /// <para> * The first field is the type of client which is calling the web service. “c” represents an individual customer.</para>
    /// <para> * The second field is the security type. “bas” represents Basic Authentication.</para>
    /// <para> * With basic authentication the third field is the username which is usually in email address notation.</para>
    /// <para> * With basic authentication the fourth field is the password associated with the user.</para>
    /// <para>If the username and password are not valid, then the credential will prevent the specified function from proceeding. A SOAP exception will be generated and sent back to the client that called the function. The message contained in the exception will contain the string “Access Denied.”</para>
    /// </summary>
    public class EdgeCast : IDisposable
    {
        #region Declarations
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static EdgeCast _current;
        private static EdgeCastCredential _credential = null;
        private static string _customerID = string.Empty;
        private static edgeCastWS _edgeCastWS = null;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public EdgeCast()
        {
            if (_current != null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Only one ContentDeliveryNetwork may be created on a given thread.");
            }
            _current = this;
            _edgeCastWS = new edgeCastWS();
            ConstructCredentials();
            _customerID = AppSettings.EdgeCast_CustomerID;
        }
        #endregion

        #region API Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Purges a file from all of the EdgeCast caching servers. This process may take a few minutes to fully complete.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Path">This is path of the file or folder to purge, in URL format. To specify a folder, please put a trailing slash at the end of the URL. All files under that folder will be purged</param>
        /// <param name="MediaType">HTTP Large Object = 3, HTTP Small Object = 8, Flash = 2, Windows = 1</param>
        /// <returns>An integer that indicates whether or not the transaction was successful. 0 represents yes, -1 represents no</returns>
        internal static short PurgeFileFromEdge(string Path, int MediaType)
        {
            return _edgeCastWS.PurgeFileFromEdge(_credential.Credential, _customerID, Path, MediaType);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Loads a file to disk on all of the EdgeCast caching servers. This process may take a few minutes to fully complete.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Path">This is path of the file to load, in URL format. Folders may not be loaded and will be ignored</param>
        /// <param name="MediaType">HTTP Large Object = 3, HTTP Small Object = 8</param>
        /// <returns>An integer that indicates whether or not the transaction was successful. 0 represents yes, -1 represents no</returns>
        internal static short LoadFileToEdge(string Path, int MediaType)
        {
            return _edgeCastWS.LoadFileToEdge(_credential.Credential, _customerID, Path, MediaType);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This method call is used to add a token authentication directory. All additions and changes should be processed every 30 minutes
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Dir">Directory Path should be starting from the root. Example: /directory1/directory2</param>
        /// <param name="MediaType">Use 1 for Windows, 2 for Flash, 3 for HTTP Caching / Progressive download.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        internal static short TokenDirAdd(string Dir, int MediaType)
        {
            return _edgeCastWS.TokenDirAdd(_credential.Credential, _customerID, Dir, MediaType);
        }
        internal static string TokenEncrypt(string Key, string Args)
        {
            return _edgeCastWS.TokenEncrypt(_credential.Credential, Key, Args);
        }
        internal static short TokenKeyUpdate(string Key, int MediaType)
        {
            return _edgeCastWS.TokenKeyUpdate(_credential.Credential, _customerID, Key, MediaType);
        }
        #endregion

        #region FTP Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Does a FTP Upload of a file on the local system
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetPath">The full path to save to on the FTP server (.\Campaigns\Prod\[Company GUID])</param>
        /// <param name="sourceFileName">The full path and filename of the file to be uploaded (C:\[DOMAIN]\files\[filename])</param>
        internal static void FTP_UploadFile(string targetPath, string sourceFileName)
        {
            string[] dirs = targetPath.Split(new char[] { '\\', '/' });

            using (FTPFactory myFTP = new FTPFactory())
            {
                myFTP.login();
                myFTP.setBinaryMode(true);

                // Make sure the directories are there and change down to the bottom most directory...
                foreach (string dirName in dirs)
                {
                    bool dirExists = true;
                    try { myFTP.chdir(dirName); }
                    catch { dirExists = false; }
                    if (!dirExists)
                    {
                        myFTP.mkdir(dirName);
                        myFTP.chdir(dirName);
                    }
                }

                // upload the file now...
                myFTP.upload(sourceFileName);
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a string array of files in the target directory
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetPath">The target directory</param>
        /// <returns>string array or null if no files found</returns>
        internal static string[] FTP_GetFileList(string targetPath)
        {
            string[] dirs = targetPath.Split(new char[] { '\\', '/' });
            string[] files = null;

            using (FTPFactory myFTP = new FTPFactory())
            {
                myFTP.login();
                myFTP.setBinaryMode(true);

                // Make sure the directories are there and change down to the bottom most directory...
                foreach (string dirName in dirs)
                {
                    bool dirExists = true;
                    try { myFTP.chdir(dirName); }
                    catch { dirExists = false; }
                    if (!dirExists)
                    {
                        myFTP.mkdir(dirName);
                        myFTP.chdir(dirName);
                    }
                }

                // get the list of files now...
                files = myFTP.getFileList("*.*");
            }
            return files;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks to see if a file exists
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="targetPath">The CDN directory path to look in</param>
        /// <param name="targetFile">The file to look for</param>
        /// <returns>true = found, false = not found</returns>
        internal static bool FTP_DoesFileExist(string targetPath, string targetFile)
        {
            bool retFlag = true;
            string[] dirs = targetPath.Split(new char[] { '\\', '/' });

            using (FTPFactory myFTP = new FTPFactory())
            {
                myFTP.login();
                myFTP.setBinaryMode(true);

                // change to the target directory - if it does not exists, neither does the file!  simple...
                foreach (string dirName in dirs)
                {
                    try { myFTP.chdir(dirName); }
                    catch { retFlag = false; }
                }
                if (retFlag)
                {
                    try { retFlag = myFTP.getFileSize(targetFile) > 0; }
                    catch { retFlag = false; }
                }
            }
            return retFlag;
        }
        internal static bool FTP_DoesFileExist(string targetFile)
        {
            string targetPath = targetFile.Replace(@"http://", "");
            targetPath = targetPath.Replace(@"https://", "");
            targetPath = targetPath.Replace(@"cdn1.[DOMAIN].com/", "");
            targetPath = targetPath.Replace(@"/", @"\");

            targetPath = targetPath.Substring(0, targetPath.LastIndexOf(@"\"));
            targetFile = targetFile.Substring(targetFile.LastIndexOf(@"/") + 1);
            return FTP_DoesFileExist(targetPath, targetFile);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Helper Methods
        static private string ConstructCredentials()
        {
            _credential = new EdgeCastCredential();
            return _credential.Credential;
        }
        static private string ConstructCredentials(string credentials)
        {
            _credential = new EdgeCastCredential(credentials);
            return _credential.Credential;
        }
        static private string ConstructCredentials(string typeOfClient, string securityType, string userName, string password)
        {
            _credential = new EdgeCastCredential(typeOfClient, securityType, userName, password);
            return _credential.Credential;
        }
        #endregion

        #region IDisposable Members
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _current = null;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**EdgeCastCredential.cs**

```
using System;
using rivSecurity = [DOMAIN].Security.Cryptography.Internal;

namespace [DOMAIN].IO.ContentDeliveryNetwork
{
    internal class EdgeCastCredential
    {
        #region Properties
        public string TypeOfClient;
        public string SecurityType;
        public string UserName;
        public string Password;
        public string Credential { get { return String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", TypeOfClient, SecurityType, UserName, Password); } }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public EdgeCastCredential()
        {
            TypeOfClient = AppSettings.EdgeCast_TypeOfClient;
            SecurityType = AppSettings.EdgeCast_SecurityType;
            UserName = rivSecurity.Decrypt(AppSettings.EdgeCast_UserName);
            Password = rivSecurity.Decrypt(AppSettings.EdgeCast_Password);
        }
        public EdgeCastCredential(string credentials)
        {
            string[] parts = credentials.Split(new char[] { ':' });
        }
        public EdgeCastCredential(string typeOfClient, string securityType, string userName, string password)
        {
            TypeOfClient = typeOfClient;
            SecurityType = securityType;
            UserName = userName;
            Password = password;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind.  I created a FTP library and used what little they had for an API.  I can <strike>not</strike> *now* read/upload/delete files and purge the CDN.

Comment: Did you mean to say "I can now"?

Comment: @Keith, can you share your library? Thanks.